# Thread cannot stop

Tags: java, multithreading

why my thread can't be stopped???

```
 class Threadz {

    class runP implements Runnable {
        int num;
        private volatile boolean exit = false;
        Thread t;
        public runP() {
            t = new Thread(this, "T1");
            t.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(!exit) {
                System.out.println(t.currentThread().getName()+": "+num);
                num++;  
                try {
                    t.sleep(200);   
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }
        public void stop() {
            exit = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        runP rp = new Threadz().new runP();
        if(rp.num == 1) {rp.stop();}
    }

}
```

if i use rp.num == 0, the thread can be stopped immediately. But, why when i changed the rp.num == x (x is any number greater than 0) the thread cannot stop? please help me solve this thing... thanks for any helps.

Comment: I guess `runP rp = new Threadz().new runP();` is creating and starting the thread. However, `if(rp.num == 1) {rp.stop();}` right after that _might_ be executed right before that other thread did actually start running so `num` is still 0. Additionally the thread could already have run multiple times thus checking for `rp.num == 1` is _very_ fragile and will probably more often fail than not.

Comment: Please consider using `rp.num > 1` instead of `rp.num ==1 ` for stopping your thread to make sure you don't accidently skip your stop condition.

Comment: You need to use AtomicBoolean to really keep this approach. In addition you need a prefect timing between both thread to hit the ==. You are better off with >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because this code is not executed in the run() method of the thread :

```
    runP rp = new Threadz().new runP();
    if (rp.num == 1) {
        rp.stop();
    }
```

It works with 0 as the default value of int is 0.
But it is not necessarily true in all executions of the application as the thread of `runP` could run and increment`num` before the check : `if (rp.num == 0)`

Move the stop condition in the run method of the runP thread :

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(!exit) {
        System.out.println(t.currentThread().getName()+": "+num);
        num++;  
        try {
            t.sleep(200);   
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}

        if (rp.num == 1) {
          exit = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay.. tried all way i can but end up with this choice... thanks bro

Comment: btw if i have 2 threads, how to passing var from 1 thread to the other one? can you tell me how?

Comment: You are welcome :) No need to pass the variable, just sharing it between your threads. You can use an AtomicInteger that you share between the runP threads and provide the AtomicInteger  in the constructor  of runP. It should be good.

Comment: Yep. And well, I just noticed that you had 99 out of 100 rep for multithreading. So I simply added the tag to the search, and carefully decided whether there was an answer of you worth upvoting ;-)

Comment: Vacancies are over and you are back there. A real pleasure to see you back :) So was it relaxing ?  Thanks for this tag boost :) I will inspect yours. Maybe some good business to do :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you run the program many many times, It'll be a case when the program actually stops.

The reason is at the time you run the program there is much more chance of executing

```
if(rp.num == 1) {rp.stop();}
```

before `num++` in your `run()` method changes value.

However by chance you may come across a case that the loop in your run method gets executed before that if statement in your main method.

one way to make sure this happens is to continuously checking for the condition:

e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] a) {
   runP rp = new Threadz().new runP();

   while(true){
      if(rp.num == 1) {
         rp.stop(); 
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement below is getting executed before the thread starts executing the run method.

```
if(rp.num == 1) {rp.stop();}
```

Add Thread.sleep before the above statement, it works fine as it will execute this statement after starting the loop.

```
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    runP rp = new Threadz().new runP();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    if(rp.num > 1) {rp.stop();}
}
```

I have made it >1 to test.

Answer (score 0):

Checking `rp.num == 1` would have to happen exactly at a point where `rp.num` is exactly one, which is rather unlikely.

In your `main` method, you start a thread which increments `num` every 200 ms. Afterwards, you check if `num == 1`, but when exactly this code is executed depends on a lot of factors you cannot really control (scheduling of the OS, etc...). This might be after 10 ms (where the value would be 1), but could also be after 300 ms (when the value is already 2). Also when the thread is exactly started is unsure. Therefore it is also possible that your thread only starts after the test. You can easily test this by replacing the check `if(rp.num == 1) {rp.stop()};` with a simple print statement `System.out.println(rp.num)`. If you additionally wait for some time before printing, you might get a better feeling of what I am talking about.

Supposing you would like to stop a runnable from outside, I suggest to use something like the [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final MyListener l;
    private volatile boolean exit;
    int num;

    public MyRunnable(MyListener l) {
        this.l = l;
        exit = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!exit) {
            System.out.println(t.currentThread().getName()+": "+num);
            l.check(num++);
            try {
                t.sleep(200);   
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        exit = true;
    }
}

class MyListener {

    private final threshold;

    public MyListener(int x) {
        this.threshold = x;
    }

    public void check(MyRunnable r, int num) {
        if (num >= threshold)
            r.stop();
    }

}
```

and your main method would look something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyListener l = new MyListener(1);
    Runnable r = new MyRunnable(l);
    new Thread(r).start();
}
```